# The email address is badly formatted Firebase/React-Native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm receiving this error when I put something different of letters (numbers or signs)...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Here is my Code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state =({
      email:'',
      password:'',
    })
  }

  signUpUser = (email, password) => {

    try {

      if(this.state.password.length <6)
      {
        alert("Please enter atleast 6 characters")
        return;
      }

      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }

    catch (error){
      console.log(error.toString())
    }
  }

  loginUser =(email, password) => {

    try{

      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user){
        console.log(user)
      })
    }

    catch (error) {
      console.log(error.toString())
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label> Email </Label>
            <Input
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCapitalize='none'
              onChangeText={(email)=> this.setState({email})} 

              />
          </Item>

          <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label> Password </Label>
            <Input
              secureTextEntry={true}
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCapitalize='none'
              onChangeText={(password)=> this.setState({password})}
              />
          </Item>

          <Button style={{marginTop: 10}}
          full
          rounded
          success
          onPress = {()=> this.loginUser(this.state.email,this.state.password)}
          >
            <Text> Login </Text>
          </Button>

          <Button style={{marginTop: 10}}
          full
          rounded
          primary
          onPress = {()=> this.signUpUser(this.state.email,this.state.password)}
          >
            <Text style={{color: 'white' }}> Sign Up </Text>
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 10
  }
})
```

[image]

Comment: What email address fails?  Try logging what you are sending to firebase.

Comment: Fails when I add some numbers/signs in the email, except characters

Comment: Please be more specific.  What email address fails?

Comment: For example - react-native12@gmail.com (this will fail) but

Comment: Reactnative@gmail.com - this will work

Comment: Try logging what is getting sent to firebase - for example, in your `loginUser` method call `console.log('email ',email)`

Comment: In catch or in try ?

Comment: No, didn't work

Comment: It sends the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix "Email is badly formatted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074023/how-can-i-fix-email-is-badly-formatted)